# How to center a div responsively which contains nested circles?

Tags: html, css

I have absolute positioned inner circles and I centered them succesfully like below.There is text inside the smallest circle also centered.

[image]

Problem is when I want to make it responsive which is also reducing the width.Scroll bar happens which I dont want and showd you as red labeled.I want my circles to be cropped from left and right sides as I'm reducing the width.How can I do that?

[image]

```css
body{
background-color:blue;
}
 #first-circle {
   border-radius: 50%;
   width: 643px;
   height: 643px;
   border: 1px solid #FFFFFF;
   position: absolute;
   top:28px;
   border: 1px solid rgba(255, 255, 255);
   left: 50%; 
   transform: translate(-50%,0);
 }
 #second-circle {
   position: absolute;
   border-radius: 50%;
   border: 1px solid rgba(255, 255, 255);
   width: 508px;
   height: 508px;
   top: 50%;
   left: 50%;
   margin: -254px 0px 0px -254px;
 }

 #third-circle {
    position: absolute;
    width: 382px;
    height: 382px;
    border: 1px solid rgba(255, 255, 255);
    box-sizing: border-box;
    border-radius: 50%;
    top: 50%;
    left: 50%;
    margin: -191px 0px 0px -191px;
  }

  #fourth-circle {
    position: absolute;
    width: 254px;
    height: 254px;
    border: 1px solid rgba(255, 255, 255);
    box-sizing: border-box;
    border-radius: 50%;
    top: 50%;
    left: 50%;
    margin: -127px 0px 0px -127px;
  }

  #fifth-circle {
    position: absolute;
    font-size:14px;
    width: 128px;
    height: 128px;
    text-align: center;
    color:#fff;
    border: 1px solid rgba(255, 255, 255,.8);
    box-sizing: border-box;
    border-radius: 50%;
    top: 50%;
    left: 50%;
    margin: -64px 0px 0px -64px;
  }
  .text-container{
  margin-top:50px;
  }
```

```html
    <div id="first-circle">   
                          <div id="second-circle" >
                              <div id="third-circle" >
                                <div id="fourth-circle">
                                  <div id="fifth-circle">
                                       <div class="text-container">
                                       Text goes here
                                      </div>       
                                  </div>
                                </div>
                              </div>
                          </div>
                         </div>
```

Comment: Adding `overflow:hidden` to the body will remove the scroll bar but I'm not sure what you mean by making this "responsive". You're using fixed pixel values so you'd have to adjust all of those first.

Answer (score 1):

Set 
`overflow="hidden"`
on body or i can be your outer div

Answer (score 0):

If you want to show always all the circles, you must edit all the width and height pixels to vw/vh to make it scale with the page.
If you want to crop the 'image', you can set the overflow to hidden, and the circles will be cropped.

Answer (score 0):

pixel is the worst unit to do this
 you can use `vh`
if you want your text to fit inside your smallest circle , you can assign bigger values respectively to them

```css
body{
background-color:blue;
}
 #first-circle {
   border-radius: 50%;
   width: 90vh;
   height: 90vh;
   border: 1px solid #FFFFFF;
   position: absolute;
   top:28px;
   border: 1px solid rgba(255, 255, 255);
   left: 50%; 
   transform: translate(-50%,0) , scale(2);
 }
 #second-circle {
   position: absolute;
   border-radius: 50%;
   border: 1px solid rgba(255, 255, 255);
   width: 70vh;
   height: 70vh;
   top: 10vh;
   left: 10vh;
   
 }

 #third-circle {
    position: absolute;
       width: 50vh;
   height: 50vh;
   top: 10vh;
   left: 10vh;
    border: 1px solid rgba(255, 255, 255);
    box-sizing: border-box;
    border-radius: 50%;
  
   
  }

  #fourth-circle {
    position: absolute;
           width: 30vh;
   height: 30vh;
   top: 10vh;
   left: 10vh;
    border: 1px solid rgba(255, 255, 255);
    box-sizing: border-box;
    border-radius: 50%;
   
   
  }

  #fifth-circle {
    position: absolute;
    font-size:14px;
               width: 10vh;
   height: 10vh;
   top: 10vh;
   left: 10vh;
    text-align: center;
    color:#fff;
    border: 1px solid rgba(255, 255, 255,.8);
    box-sizing: border-box;
    border-radius: 50%;
 
  
  }
  .text-container{
  margin-top:0px;
  font-size: 1em;
  }
```

```html
  <div id="first-circle">   
                          <div id="second-circle" >
                              <div id="third-circle" >
                                <div id="fourth-circle">
                                  <div id="fifth-circle">
                                       <div class="text-container">
                                       
                                      </div>       
                                  </div>
                                </div>
                              </div>
                          </div>
                         </div>
```